# Программа крашится из-за вызова push_back()

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

есть класс

```
class Char{
public:
    enum Type
    {
    None = 0,
    Image,
    Text
    };

    Char(const char &c = ' ')
    {
        _c = c;
        _TextColor = new Colors::Color(TextColor);
        _BackgroundColor = new Colors::Color(BackgroundColor);
        _type = Type::Text;
    }

    Char(const Images::img &img);


    ~Char()
    {
        Free();
    }


    protected:
    Images::img *_img;
    char _c;

    private:
    void Free()
    {
        switch (_type)
        {
        case Type::Image:
            delete _img;
            break;
        case Type::Text:
            delete _TextColor;
            delete _BackgroundColor;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    mutable unsigned *_TextColor;
    mutable unsigned *_BackgroundColor;

    unsigned _type;
};
```

и класс

```
class Text
{
public:
    Text(const std::string &t)
    {
        SetText(t);
    }
    
    
    void SetText(const std::string &text)
    {
        _data.clear();
        _data.reserve(text.length());
    
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
        {
            _data.push_back(Char(text.at(i)));
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<Char> _data;
};
```

Так вот при втором вызове push_back() в функции Text::SetText(std::string) присходит краш
и я вообще хз что нетак

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three